# Entity with field Array of objects. How to correctly describe this Entity use Hibernate ogm?

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I am a tester. I 'm doing my first java automation project using Hibernate ogm. I 've been thinking about this problem several days, but I can 't find a solution.

This is my document in bd:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tvPX.jpg)

This is Entity:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYBHJ.jpg)

I have difficulty describing the fields from the red frame. Without these fields there are no problems, my test works. As soon as I add fields from the red frame, my SessionFactory falls. I have no idea how to do it right. I will be glad of any help and advice.

Comment: Please explicitly include your code avoid to link images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Julia, personal names in Latin are readable for all folks, and thus more welcome here